# low-latency ADC and DAC

Tags: analog-to-digital, digital-to-analog

I am recently trying to use ADC and DAC with low latency and high speed. I wonder what are the ADCs and DACs with the lowest latency over 1Gsps?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Start by defining what you mean by "low latency".  _I_ may think that one whole second is astonishingly low latency.  You may not.